# Multiple If statements with BETWEEN

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I am a little stuck on the middle part of my Excel VBA function.  I am attempting to calculate the difference between two dates and show a result if they fall into three parameters.

This is what I have:

```
=IF(SUM(42370-T4/365)<=4,20,IF(SUM(42370-T4/365)>=5,25,IF(SUM(42370-T4/365)>10,30,"")))
```

I think I need to throw in an AND function right in the middle there as I am trying to find a date that is >=5 years but less than 10.

So I want to see:

```
1-4 Years = 20
5-9 Years = 25
10+ Years = 30
```

Comment: Given basic mathematical hierarchy, wouldn't that be `SUM((42370-T4)/365)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula will work in order so flip the second if statement around to check if the date is less than or equal to 9 like so:

```
=IF(SUM(42370-T4/365)<=4,20,IF(SUM(42370-T4/365)<=9,25,IF(SUM(42370-T4/365)>10,30,"")))
```

Comment: This is directly what I asked for.  Thank you.

Comment: @Yogwhatup - So you did indeed want to first divide the value in T4 by 365 before subtracting it from 01-Jan-2016...? Odd that.

Answer (score 1):

I've converted your `42370` to `DATE(2016, 1, 1)` and used the [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) as an accurate method of advancing months and/or years.

```
=IF(EDATE(T4, 12)>=DATE(2016, 1, 1), "", 20+((EDATE(T4, 60)<DATE(2016, 1, 1))*5)+((EDATE(T4, 120)<DATE(2016, 1, 1))*5))
```

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: Smart way of doing this.  I like it.  Thank you for the help.  This appears to have solved the issue.